Equidistant points along an Archimedean spiral with fixed gap between points and between spiral turns
I would like to place points equidistantly along an Archimedean spiral, with a fixed gap between each point along the spiral and between each turn of the spiral, as shown in the attached image. How can I achieve this?

For example, in the image, three red points indicate where I want the points to be equidistant. Each point represents a hole. I've attempted to achieve this using the code below, but modifying the theta and radius parameters doesn't seem to work as expected:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_membranes(Nx, Ny, radius, height, output_path):
    hole = create_holes(radius, height)
    patch_size = hole.shape[0]

    image = np.full((Nx + 2 * patch_size, Ny + 2 * patch_size), height)

    theta = np.arange(0, max([Nx,Ny]) * np.pi, 0.0001)
    r = radius * theta / np.pi * 1.414 
    x = np.floor(Nx // 2. + r * np.cos(theta))
    y = np.floor(Ny // 2. + r * np.sin(theta))

    # Correction of x and y values to ensure they are valid
    x = np.clip(x, patch_size, Nx + patch_size - 1).astype(np.int32)
    y = np.clip(y, patch_size, Ny + patch_size - 1).astype(np.int32)

    for i in range(len(x)):
        if patch_size < x[i] < Nx + patch_size and patch_size < y[i] < Ny + patch_size:
            patchImage = image[x[i] - radius: x[i] + radius + 1, y[i] - radius: y[i] + radius + 1]
            if np.sum(patchImage) == height * patchImage.size:
                image[x[i] - radius: x[i] + radius + 1, y[i] - radius: y[i] + radius + 1] = hole

    return image

Nx, Ny = 300, 300
radius = 2
height = 80
output_path = ""

generate_membranes(Nx, Ny, radius, height, output_path)

I think this code only works with these parameters, but once the parameters are modified, it no longer works.

Can you more clearly clarify which distances you want to be equal?

One possibility is to plot points at equal distances along the spiral arms, that distance being equal to the separation between arms; i.e. (outer radius)/(number of turns). This gives points that are nearly, but not quite, equidistant in space, with the biggest deviation at the centre.
If the Archimedean spiral has polar equation r=a.theta then the length of arc between theta=0 and theta=t is s=(a/2)[t.sqrt(1+t^2) + ln(t+sqrt(1+t^2))]
So, find the total length, divide it into equal distances and, for each, solve iteratively for polar angle (I rearranged to do it as a quadratic equation in t^2 below). Note that if you take the distances half way along each segment you will alleviate things somewhat at the centre.
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def spiral( radius, num_cycles ):
    ''' Returns points separated by equal distance along spiral arms '''
    dr = radius / num_cycles                               # the target distance apart
    theta_max = 2 * np.pi * num_cycles                     # maximum angle
    a = radius / theta_max                                 # constant in r = a.theta
    s_max = ( a / 2 ) * ( theta_max * math.sqrt( 1 + theta_max ** 2 ) + math.log( theta_max + math.sqrt( 1 + theta_max ** 2 ) ) )
                                                           # total distance
    N = int( s_max / dr + 0.5 )                            # number of points
    s = np.linspace( dr / 2, s_max - dr / 2, N )           # individual distances (centres of the arc segments)
    theta = np.zeros( N )                                  # array to hold angles
    for i in range( N ):                                   # solve for theta, given s
        t = 0
        told = t + 1
        while abs( t - told ) > 1.0e-10:
           told, t = t, math.sqrt( ( -1 + math.sqrt( 1 + 4 * ( 2 * s[i] / a - math.log( t + math.sqrt( 1 + t ** 2 ) ) ) ** 2 ) ) / 2 )
        theta[i] = t

    r = a * theta                                          # polar equation of Archimedean spiral
    return r * np.cos( theta ), r * np.sin( theta )        # cartesian coordinates


radius, ncycle = 1, 20
x, y = spiral( radius, ncycle )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(7,7) )
ax.plot( x, y, 'ko' )
plt.show()


